# remove low counts from pandas data frame column on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas data frame:

```
new = pd.Series(np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2]))
df = pd.DataFrame(new, columns=['a'])
```

I output the occurrences of each value by:

```
print df['a'].value_counts()
```

Then I have the following:

```
0    3
2    2
1    1
dtype: int64
```

Now I want to remove the rows whose column 'a' value is less than 2. I can iterate through each value in df['a'] and remove it if its value count is less than 2, but it takes a long time for a large data frame with multiple columns. 
I can't figure out what's an efficient way to do that.

Comment: I recommend checking out the answers here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137031/pandas-dataframe-delete-rows-with-low-frequency

Answer (score 4):

You could assign you subset your `value_counts` with your condition then get index of that `Series` then with [`isin`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjVr6b3pLrKAhXMEywKHZp9BkQQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fversion%2F0.17.1%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.DataFrame.isin.html&usg=AFQjCNFCQ7VBungAK7COmIltdOVZWT_uew&bvm=bv.112064104,d.bGQ) you could check for the values which should be in your original and then pass values to the original DataFrame:

```
s = df['a'].value_counts()
df[df.isin(s.index[s >= 2]).values]
```

How it works:

```
In [133]: s.index[s >= 2]
Out[133]: Int64Index([0, 2], dtype='int64')


In [134]: df.isin(s.index[s >= 2]).values
Out[134]:
array([[ True],
       [False],
       [ True],
       [ True],
       [ True],
       [ True]], dtype=bool)


In [135]: df[df.isin(s.index[s >= 2]).values]
Out[135]:
   a
0  0
2  0
3  0
4  2
5  2
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to join the counts data with the original df.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['a'].value_counts())
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.columns = ['a','counts']

# df2 = 
#   a   counts
# 0 0   3
# 1 2   2
# 2 1   1

df3 = df.merge(df2,on='a')

# df3 = 
#   a   counts
# 0 0   3
# 1 0   3
# 2 0   3
# 3 1   1
# 4 2   2
# 5 2   2

# filter
df3[df3.counts>=2]
```