# pandas dataframe delete rows with low frequency

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the best practice to remove all rows that has a column with low frequency value?

Dataframe:

```
IN:
foo bar poo
1   a   A
2   a   A
3   a   B
4   b   B
5   b   A
6   b   A
7   c   C
8   d   B
9   e   B
```

Example 1:
Remove all rows that have less than 3 in frequency value in column 'poo':

```
OUT:
foo bar poo
1   a   A
2   a   A
3   a   B
4   b   B
5   b   A
6   b   A
8   d   B
9   e   B
```

Example 2:
Remove all rows that have less than 3 in frequency value in column 'bar':

```
OUT:
foo bar poo
1   a   A
2   a   A
3   a   B
4   b   B
5   b   A
6   b   A
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should generalise pretty easily. You'll need `groupby` + `transform` + `count`, and then filter the result:

```
col = 'poo'  # 'bar'
n = 3        # 2

df[df.groupby(col)[col].transform('count').ge(n)]

   foo bar poo
0    1   a   A
1    2   a   A
2    3   a   B
3    4   b   B
4    5   b   A
5    6   b   A
7    8   d   B
8    9   e   B
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand why this works so much faster than the previous suggestion you made, where it took over a minute. This works instantly!

Comment: @AnonX An interesting takeaway from our last Q&A exchange is that groupby slows down horribly for series (df.eq(..) generates a series). Very interesting.

Answer (score 5):

IIUC filter ..

```
df.groupby('poo').filter(lambda x : (x['poo'].count()>=3).any())
Out[81]: 
   foo bar poo
0    1   a   A
1    2   a   A
2    3   a   B
3    4   b   B
4    5   b   A
5    6   b   A
7    8   d   B
8    9   e   B
```

Or combine `value_counts` with `isin`

```
s=df.poo.value_counts().gt(3)
df.loc[df.poo.isin(s[s].index)]
Out[89]: 
   foo bar poo
0    1   a   A
1    2   a   A
2    3   a   B
3    4   b   B
4    5   b   A
5    6   b   A
7    8   d   B
8    9   e   B
```

Comment: Second option = much faster. Thanks! :)