# How to drop a row that has a wrong (unknown) value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains, delete-row

I am trying to delete a row that has a wrong, but the unknown value in one column.

my data frame looks something like this

```
'size'  : ['small', 'small', 'medium','small','small'],
'length': [38, 62, 55,33,22],
'kinds' : ["A","#$" ,"B","C","A"]}
```

I want to drop the row that has the wrong value. The value is wrong if the value doesn't contain
any value in kinds

```
kinds=["A","B","C"]
```

I tried something like this

```
df[df["kinds"].contains(kinds)]
```

but I couldn't use contains..

What should I do?

Comment: By the look of it , isin should do:  `df[df["kinds"].isin(kinds)]`

Comment: _but I couldn't use contains.._ What do you mean?

Comment: @anky_91 yes it worked ! thanks

Comment: @AMC I thought I could use 'contains' I saw .contains() from somewhere, but it was my mistake

Comment: @JiyoungLee Right, but what happens when you use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[remove low counts from pandas data frame column on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913546/remove-low-counts-from-pandas-data-frame-column-on-condition)

you should delete low counted outlier categorical values:

```
for name in df.columns:
    if df[name].dtypes == 'O':
        s = df[name].value_counts()
        df = df[df.isin(s.index[s >= 3]).values] # 3 value that proper for action.
```

If it is a numeric value, then you should apply outlier analysis. You can also change the categorical values into numeric delete outliers and transform the numerical into categorical if you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
newdf = df[df['kinds'].isin(kinds)]
```

You just want to check if the value in the column is in your list.